# Using URL Scheme to get background runtime on another app

Tags: ios, iphone, appdelegate, url-scheme

Can I use the `URL Scheme` mechanism in app 1 to get a background `runtime` in app 2?

I mean to avoid app 2 lunching?

In the app 1 I do:

```
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myScheme://"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:myUrl]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myUrl];
    }
```

In app 2, this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation;
```

Can I avoid from lunching app 2, and get this method (or any other related method) to run in background?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you can certainly start a background task, when this method is triggered.

Comment: Thanks @k6sandeep, But it won't avoid the app 2 lunching... :/

Comment: You should return no in the method.

Comment: I don't think it's right, see the doc: `YES if the delegate successfully handled the request or NO if the attempt to open the URL resource failed.` And I check it now.. Still, app 2 is lunch.